# where can I learn linked list/stacks?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

As the question stated above, is there any recommended sites to study them??
I've searched online, but mostly give the entire code without teaching what the code does

for example, what does -> do??

btw: I wanna learn these 2 which are for C Programming

Comment: `some_pointer->something` is equivalent to `(*some_pointer).something`

Comment: Try MIT's opencourseware for some intro data structures courses

Comment: a recommended [site from me](http://google.com) to find answer for this kind of questions. Also a recommended page: [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Take a look at [Stanford CS Education Library](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links will help.  There is other good stuff at the site as well.  And it is C oriented.

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/